# Does a canada student visa refusal affect a student visa for other countries?

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals

I am looking to apply for a study visa in Canada. I got an admission for a Bachelor of Science degree at Memorial University of Newfoundland, but the issue is that my marks in Maths were not good enough.

My overall percent in 12th is 62 percent and in 10th 72 percent. I have paid the university fees but I am really worried at this point about whether applying for the visa is worth it or not. I feel like I should do my bachelors in India and after improving my grades in maths then I should apply.

If my student visa gets rejected, will it effect my visa application to other countries in future?

Comment: fixed,sorry about it.

Answer (score 5):

Your university admission depends on your grades.

Your visa application depends on the perception that you will follow the laws while you are in Canada and that you will leave when your visa ends.

If you have the university admission, the grades won't be a problem any more.

Comment: the visa officers in My country do care about grades.I have heard about students getting visa refusal from embassy if the embassy feels that His grades in a particular subject are less.I have heard sometimes the visa officer feels that the student is not genuine student if his marks are not good.

Comment: If you have the university admission and the grades required for that admission before you apply for the visa, why should the embassy effectively decide to overrule the university’s admission decision?

Comment: Because they don't feel that student is not good enough according to their own standards.If the visa officer feels that the student might not be able to cope with studies in canada his visa might get rejected.https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/visa-rejected-spp-jan-2013.122726/

Comment: If the visa officials were to reject an application on the grounds of grades it would be because they thought the school was not a 'real' school and was givingvthe student a fake admission. Memorial is very much a real school with a good reputation and will not be giving out fake admissions.

Comment: Visa rejection based on grades only happen when the school is hardly known of, and the students don't seem to be genuinely intending to study (rather, e.g., intending to work/live illegally in the country while pretending to study). Memorial might not be the best university in Canada, but it's a very established and well-known school, known to enforce their own (claimed) admissions standards and good academic standards.

Comment: I have not heard of a student going to a well-established school and having enough financial capability being denied a visa unless something very ridiculous happens, e.g. the applicant apparently could not speak English, or the applicant could not name the school they're going to.